# How to load a file content in a text area using $?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i would like to show a style sheet content in a text area is a user select a style in select box. The style sheet is in server so i tried load and get both doesn't work form me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sel').change(function() { 
     jQuery.get('style1.css',function(data) {
     jQuery('#cs').html(data);
     alert('Load was performed.');
     });

   // jQuery('#cs').load('style1.css'); 

    }); 
});
    </script>
```

Html

```
<select id="sel">
 <option value="style1">style1</option>
 <option value="style2">style2</option>
</select>
```

I'm getting load was performed alert but not the content in the text area.

Here `#cs` is the id of my text area.

Comment: Where is the textarea..?

Comment: Define _doesn't work for me_, please.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/bNvuA/  - it works for me, make sure you don't get 404 on your css

Comment: Pretty sure "doesn't work for me" is relatively clear in this case Aleks G

Comment: @AleksG did i say wrong anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the value of a textarea with `val()` not `html()`.

Comment: why not html?can i show content from file with php extension?

Comment: Because that is how textareas work. They have values. You can show (sane) content from any URL you like (subject to the same origin policy). File extensions are meaningless on the WWW, only Content-Type matters.

Comment: Thanks.One more question should i mention content type every time because here it is working without content type now.

Comment: The content-type is specified by the server (unless you are making a POST request, in which case the request made by the client needs one too). You are loading what appears to be a static file with a common file type. Unless you are doing something unusual, the server will handle the content type for you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use val.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sel').change(function() { 
     jQuery.get('style1.css',function(data) {
     jQuery('#cs').val(data);
     alert('Load was performed.');
     });

   // jQuery('#cs').load('style1.css'); 

    });
```